# Sharding Spring Boot app with reader and writter

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jhipster

We created app using JHipster on Spring Boot. Our app scaled a lot and our main issue is database scaling and performances. How is it possible to make 2 DB process in spring boot where one will act as writer and other one will act as reader ?

Comment: Have you tried defining 2 datasources one with a user that has full read/write permissions and another one that can only read?

Comment: No and that is to complicated, is it possible that there is no support for such a important thing in spring framework ?

Comment: What is complicated in this approach? This is how it is usually done in Spring, defining a `@Primary` datasource bean, there are plenty examples and docs about it. Alternatively, you could use a db pool loadbalancer server side, like pg-pool for postgresql.

Comment: Can you please give me example of how it's done ?

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases

Comment: another good one: https://springframework.guru/how-to-configure-multiple-data-sources-in-a-spring-boot-application/

Comment: Both of your articles have nothing to do with my question. You both sent me how to put different entities in different databases. I need to create reader and writer on same database. That is not explained in articles you provided